# NSLayoutManager glyph generation and caret position

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, nstextview

I have a text editor app, which uses Markdown-style formatting. Formatting characters are hidden when caret/selection is not on the corresponding line.

I'm successfully using `shouldGenerateGlyphs:` method in `NSLayoutManagerDelegate` to manipulate what is drawn on `NSTextView`. I'm using pure delegation and haven't subclassed the layout manager itself.

However, I can't understand how I can position the caret correctly after glyph regeneration. After selection has changed, I'm calling a method (here called `hideAndShowMarkup`) which regenerates glyphs for both the line currently edited and the one that was selected earlier. Because some glyphs are added on screen, caret gets rendered wrong.

```objectivec
-(void)hideAndShowMarkup {
    [self.layoutManager invalidateGlyphsForCharacterRange:currentLine.range changeInLength:0 actualCharacterRange:nil];
    [self.layoutManager invalidateGlyphsForCharacterRange:prevLine.range changeInLength:0 actualCharacterRange:nil];
    
    [self.layoutManager ensureGlyphsForCharacterRange:currentLine.range];
    [self.layoutManager ensureGlyphsForCharacterRange:prevLine.range];

    [self updateInsertionPointStateAndRestartTimer:YES];
}
```

`updateInsertionPoint...` doesn't work here, as ensuring glyphs seems to run asynchronously.  I've tried calling it in `didCompleteLayoutForTextContainer:` delegate method too, but to no effect.

Is there a way to detect when the glyphs have actually been drawn, and to ensure insertion point position after that?

Comment: One of `invalidateGlyphsForCharacterRange` and `ensureGlyphsForCharacterRange` shouldn't be needed. Post a [mre] please.

Comment: I found a solution by browsing random GitHub repositories and will post my findings, as there have been multiple questions touching same subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSLayoutManager` is surprisingly poorly documented, and understanding its inner workings required looking through implementations in random public repositories.

To change glyphs in a range and have the caret position correctly, you first need to invalidate glyphs for both of the changed ranges, and then invalidate the **layout** for the range the caret is about to be positioned in.

Then, after making sure that there is a current graphic context, glyphs can be redrawn synchronously. After this, updating insertion point works normally.

In the example below, I have two objects, `line` and `prevLine` which contain ranges for both the line on which caret is positioned now, and the one caret moved away from.

```objectivec
-(void)hideAndShowMarkup {
    [self.layoutManager invalidateGlyphsForCharacterRange:line.range changeInLength:0 actualCharacterRange:nil];
    [self.layoutManager invalidateGlyphsForCharacterRange:prevLine.range changeInLength:0 actualCharacterRange:nil];
    [self.layoutManager invalidateLayoutForCharacterRange:line.range actualCharacterRange:nil];
        
    if (NSGraphicsContext.currentContext) {
        [self.layoutManager drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:line.range atPoint:self.frame.origin];
        [self.layoutManager drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:prevLine.range atPoint:self.frame.origin];
    }
    
    [self updateInsertionPointStateAndRestartTimer:NO];
}
```